# R double loop with where

Tags: r, while-loop

I have the the following data frame and variables:

```
u0 <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame (u0)
a = .793
b = 2.426
r = 0.243
q = 1
w = 2
j = 1
z = .314
```

using the following loop I am doing some calculations and put the results in the first row of my data frame.

```
while (j<5){
  df[q,w] <- df[q, w-1] * (r+j-1)*(b+j-1)*(z) / ((a+b+j-2)*j)
  j = j + 1
  w = w + 1
}
```

now I want to create another loop to do the same calculations for all rows (i.e I need the 'q' variable to vary) of my data frame. I would be thankful if anyone helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either do this by putting your `while` loop inside of a `for` loop that goes over `q`, but a more R-tastic way would be to simply define `q <- 1:5`, and leave the rest of your code as-is. Then `df` will fill up entirely. I take it in this example you want all rows to be identical?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put it in a for loop?

```
df <- data.frame (d1=u0, d2=u0+1, d3=u0+2, d4=u0+4, d5=u0+5)
for (q in 2:5) {
while (j<5){
  df[q,w] <- df[q, w-1] * (r+j-1)*(b+j-1)*(z) / ((a+b+j-2)*j)
  j = j + 1
  w = w + 1
           }    }
```

You may want to check the algorithm. It doesn't seem to be doing anything very interesting.